# How to prove that the sequence $S$ has a limit? $\lim a_n = a$, $S_{n + 1} = \frac{ S_n \sqrt{n} + \frac{a_{n + 1}}{\sqrt{n + 1}} }{\sqrt{n + 1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to prove that the sequence $S$ has a limit? $\lim a_n = a$, $S_{n + 1} = \frac{ S_n \sqrt{n}  + \frac{a_{n + 1}}{\sqrt{n + 1}} }{\sqrt{n + 1}}$. This formula is recursive for $S_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(a_1 + \frac{a_2}{\sqrt{2}} + \ldots + \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}})$. I need to find $\lim S_n$. I assumed it exists, and found $\lim S_n=\frac{a}{2}$. Now I need to prove it. At the moment I know two ways to prove it: if the sequence is monotonous or using Stolz theorem. First is 100% wrong, I tried second but failed. Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $S_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(a_1 + \frac{a_2}{\sqrt{2}} + \ldots + \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}})\to 2a$ as $ n\to \infty$. $S_n-2a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}((a_1-a) + \frac{(a_2-a)}{\sqrt{2}} + \ldots + \frac{(a_n-a}{\sqrt{n}}) +[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(a + \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} + \ldots + \frac{a}{\sqrt{n}})-2a]$. Split the sum in the first term into two parts: The first $k$ the and the remaining $n-k$.  Choose $k$ such that $|a_i-a| <\epsilon $ for $i \geq k$. Now you will need the fact that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(1 + \frac1 {\sqrt{2}} + \ldots + \frac 1 {\sqrt{n}})$ is bounded. For this compare this with $\frac  1 {\sqrt n} \int_k^{n} \frac  1{\sqrt x}dx$ and evaluate this integral explicitly. Finally show that $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(a + \frac{a}{\sqrt{2}} + \ldots + \frac{a}{\sqrt{n}})-2a \to 0$ again by comparison with above integral.